403 Forbidden Error During Login in Spring Boot Application
Have a good day.
I am facing an issue when verifying the user osamazaza200 with the correct password (test123) during login in my Spring Boot application. Despite providing the proper credentials, the authentication process fails, and a 403 error is returned.
Steps to Reproduce
Create a user with the following credentials:
Username: osamazaza200
Password: test123 (hashed and stored in the database)
Attempt to sign in using the /signin endpoint with the credentials.
Observe the response, which results in a 403 Forbidden error.
Relevant Code:
Fristly: Security Config Class:
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService){
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        
    AuthenticationConfiguration configuration)
    
    throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                        //authorize.anyRequest().authenticated() 
                        authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                );

        return http.build();
    }
}


Secondly: AuthController
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.controllers;

 


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<String> authenticateUser(@RequestBody LoginDto loginDto){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginDto.getUsernameOrEmail(), loginDto.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User signed-in successfully!.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody SignUpDto signUpDto){

        // add check for username exists in a DB
        if(userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpDto.getUsername())){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Username is already taken!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // add check for email exists in DB
        if(userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpDto.getEmail())){
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Email is already taken!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // create user object
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(signUpDto.getName());
        user.setUsername(signUpDto.getUsername());
        user.setEmail(signUpDto.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(signUpDto.getPassword()));

        Role roles = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_ADMIN").get();
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(roles));

        userRepository.save(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>("User registered successfully", HttpStatus.OK);

    }
}


Thirdly: Login DTO
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.dto;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class LoginDto {
    private String usernameOrEmail;
    private String password;
}


Fourthly: Sign UP DTO
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.dto;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SignUpDto {
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}


Fifthly: Role Class
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String name;
}



Sixthly: User Role Class
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.entity;

import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.persistence.*; 
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"username"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})
})
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
}


Seventhly: Role Repository Class
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.entity.Role;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    Optional<Role> findByName(String name);
}


Eighty: User Repository Class
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
    Optional<User> findByUsernameOrEmail(String username, String email);
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
    Boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}


Ninthly: CustomUserDetailsService
package com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.services;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.entity.User;
import com.muhammedessa.securityapicrud.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {




    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usernameOrEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
          User user = userRepository.findByUsernameOrEmail(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail)
                 .orElseThrow(() ->
                         new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username or email: "+ usernameOrEmail));

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user
                .getRoles()
                .stream()
                .map((role) -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword(),
                authorities);
    }
}


Application Properties
spring.application.name=APIDemo
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/usersdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password= 

# Hibernate
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE


When running [POST] request API http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup
Body
{
"name": "Loyasl Essa",
"username": "testrer",
"email": "test123@gmail.com",
"password": "12345678"
}
getting 403 error

You can try this...
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                    //authorize.anyRequest().authenticated() 
                    authorize.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()


Same issue 403 issue
